# How to delete webhooks on uninstall

Tags: api, uninstallation, bigcommerce, webhooks

I've created an app that is already published in the app store.
This app uses WebHooks and works well; the problem is that when I uninstall the app, the webhooks are still running.
I wonder what is the best way to remove these WebHooks at the time that the app is uninstalled. I have not found any examples for this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can set an app uninstall path in the same location you set the callback (https://developer.bigcommerce.com/ then edit your app) . This will make a call to your server when a store uninstalls the app.

At this point I

```
GET https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/{Store Context}/v2/hooks
```

to list all hooks
then iterate through the list and send a

```
DELETE https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/{Store Context}/v2/hooks/{hookId}
```